# Using Azure Media Services to Record Video using a SWF file

Tags: video, azure, flash, media, azure-media-services

We have developed a SWF file that captures the users video and audio.

We would like to use Azure Media Services to ingest and encode the recording.

Unfortunately we are finding the SWF file is better integrated with Adobe's Flash Media Server. Does anyone know if there are any work arounds? Or are we being muppets and this is already possible?

Comment: What kind of problem you are experiencing with WAMS to find workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to post this question to dedicated Windows Azure Media Services forum and you might get some directly from the Windows Media Services developers on this regard:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MediaServices/threads